# WooCommerce - Virtual Products have "No Available Payment Method"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

For some reason in my WooCommerce-enabled website, I always run into a problem in the checkout process when it deals with virtual products. For physical products I can checkout with Shipping and Payment methods fine, but whenever I try to test the checkout process on virtual products my website claims there are "No Available Payment Methods for [my] state."
In the admin panel, I have enabled COD for virtual products as a payment method as well as enabled the payment method itself and I have tried using free shipping and local pickup shipping methods in case that was the issue.

Checkout with virtual products used to work fine on COD, but ever since I updated it today the functionality ceased to exist. Is there any reason why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, I've figured out the issue myself. I guess posting Wordpress issues on Stack Overflow is a bad idea clearly.
I fixed my own problem by removing all shipping methods from the COD Payment Settings because Virtual Orders use "None" as a shipping method and can't be selected normally through the COD Shipping Method Restriction setting.

Comment: There's a dedicated StackExchange for WordPress: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/